# Prepopulating userform failed gives "type mismatch" error

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I have a Userform that can either take information from the excel sheet and prepopulate the Userform or output Userform information back to the excel sheet. The issue took place when prepopulating the Userform from excel data.

[image]

As seen in the picture above, it's the Userform itself and after clicking on Prepopulate option I get the **Run-time error "13": Type Mismatch**. So when I debugged it, it went to line 5 line seen below which corresponds to the Prepopulate section of  the code.

```
    With Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")
    If .Range("H28").value = "Chief Process Safety" Then
        ToggleButton1 = True
     Else
     If .Range("H28").value = "Senior Process Safety" Or "Interm Process Safety" Or "" Then
        ToggleButton1 = False
    End If
    End If
End With
```

[image]

The picture above is what it looks like on excel where the user inputs the fields and the last field is a drop down list to choose 1 from the three options that is linked to the piece of code within the Userform as shown above.

So I am wondering to get rid of this error do I have to assign some kind of a variable to the range possibly?

Comment: You have to repeat the `.Range("H28").Value` for each condition in the `If` statement: `If .Range("H28").Value = "Senior Process Safety" Or .Range("H28").Value = "Interm Process Safety" Or .Range("H28").Value = "" Then`.

Comment: This line? `If .Range("H28").value = "Senior Process Safety" Or "Interm Process Safety" Or "" Then`

Comment: @DavidZemens yep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better (for legibility IMO) to use a `Select Case` switch in this instance:

```
With Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")
Select Case .Range("H28").Value
    Case "Chief Process Safety"
        ToggleButton1 = True
    Case "Senior Process Safety", "Interm Process Safety", ""
        ToggleButton1 = False
End Select
End With
```

Alternatively, you need to properly construct your boolean expression:

```
If .Range("H28").value = "Senior Process Safety" Or _
   .Range("H28").value = "Interm Process Safety" Or _
   .Range("H28").value = "" Then
```

**Because** as currently constructed, your `If` statement is comparing a boolean with a string(s) which results in the Mismatch Error. Breaking it down, it is this:

```
If (.Range("H28").Value = "Senior Process Safety") Or "Interim Process Safety" Or "" Then
```

And because you can't compare these types, `If True Or "foo"` raises a mismatch error just as your code will raise the mismatch error.

Comment: There was an syntax error with the first option so I went with the second option and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: The syntax error is the extra `Then` at the end of the second `Case` - sure you know that but pointing it out to @GoldFusion.